# Планировщик заданий

Tags: cmd

Хочу настроить запуск cmd, как написано вот [тут](http://ipcfg.com/v.php?mod=tutorial&p=Examples)

Выставил запуск каждые 5 минут, но мелькает окошко. Как запустить cmd в скрытом режиме?

Установлена Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть 3 варианта:

- запускайте от другого пользователя.
- был способ скрытия описанный в инструкциях по тихой установке windows
- Используйте VBS

Скажу сразу второй вариант даже искать не буду, скажу что где-то на сайте [oszone.ru](http://oszone.ru).

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, производить открытие консоли с параметром `/c`. Например,

```
  start cmd /c
```

Comment: Имеется ввиду так, как на [скриншоте](http://i.imgur.com/Dvl0V.png)? Не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

[@ArcTimofeev](/users/8770/arctimofeev), а Вы хотите, чтобы окошко с результатами выполнения `wget` осталось на экране ?

Попробуйте запустить такой t.bat

```
wget ....
cmd /c
```

по крайней мере, запущенный

```
start t
```

он оставляет окошко, в котором можно вводить команды

Comment: Нет, вы не правильно поняли. Как раз наоборот - вообще не хочется видеть окно.
Получается, что при запуске из планировщика этот wget быстро мелькает на экране каждые пять минут. Раздражает, однако. Вот и хочется его как-то в фоне стартовать.

Comment: start /min запустит в "заиконеном" окне. Конечно иконки в строке статуса мелькать будут.

Почитайте `help start` может быть подберете нужные ключи.

Comment: Вопрос - а что и откуда запустит start?

Похоже, что я совершенно не правильно задал вопрос. Подразумевался не запуск cmd как команды, а запуск файла с расширением cmd. Ну или bat, не важно.